# How do I use calendarserver?

Tags: server, calendar

So I've installed it and these are the results of an attempt to start it:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo service calendarserver status
● calendarserver.service - LSB: Calendar and Contacts Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/calendarserver; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-02-03 12:12:09 EST; 4min 24s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Feb 03 12:12:09 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Calendar and Contacts Server...
Feb 03 12:12:09 hostname calendarserver[4663]:  * Not starting calendarserver, disabled via /etc/default/calendarserver
Feb 03 12:12:09 hostname systemd[1]: Started LSB: Calendar and Contacts Server.
Feb 03 12:16:09 hostname systemd[1]: Started LSB: Calendar and Contacts Server.
```

I think this means it was already running. How do I verify that it's working properly? I've tried connecting to it at http://127.0.0.1:8008/ but no dice.

Hmm... OK I was watching the system log and didn't see much that indicated a new server running. So I looked here as the message advises: `/etc/default/calendarserver`

Apparently the portion that starts the server is `start_calendarserver=yes` and that needs to be uncommented. A restart afterwards shows log traffic indicating a new server is running. ...but what next?

OH.

```
Feb  3 12:27:02 hostname calendarserver[5570]: txdav.common.icommondatastore.InternalDataStoreError: No such socket file: /var/run/postgresql
```

Apparently it uses Postgresql. I'll install that and restart. You would think that if it needed something there would be a dependency. Sheesh. OK. This time started without errors. Will try to hit it again. Nope.

Apparently I need to have extended file system attributes, so I've fixed that and remounted the drive.

Now I'm seeing this in the logs:

```
Feb  3 13:11:47 hostname calendarserver[10440]: usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twext/python/__pycache__/_cffi_twext_python_sacl_xe128630fxbbd600c.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I also noted the above when trying to execute some of the `calendarserver_*` scripts. ...OK I've figured that one out also. Another broken dependency which is to say that it also needs python-dev. Still not working though and this time no errors reported. :-|

Comment: Which howto did you use for Calendar server ? Did you look at /usr/share/doc/calendarserver/ ? And if you want to quickly run a calendar server, have a look at Baikal or Radicale or the one from Nextcloud. I found those much easier to configure than the Apple cal. server.

Comment: There should be a way to mark packages as "Known to be non functional" so that people don't waist time with them. :-|  Trying radicale.

Comment: My impression is that Apple calendar server is a fine piece of software, but with possibly a higher admin learning curve than some other calendar servers. Good luck with Radicale !

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```bsh
sudo apt install calendarserver postgresql
sudo -u postgres createuser caldavd --no-createdb --no-createrole --no-superuser
sudo -u postgres createdb --owner=caldavd caldav
sudo -u caldavd psql -f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txdav/common/datastore/sql_schema/current.sql caldav
```

Edit `/etc/default/calendarserver`  uncomment `start_calendar_server=yes`

reboot

For proper production mode: you need to edit the `/etc/caldavd/caldavd.plist` and enable https and point to a proper directory.

You want to have **ext4** file system for the extended attributes

YMMV

There's a [complete writeup](https://wissel.net/blog/2020/01/running-a-caldav-server-on-ubuntu.html) on the steps